# react component being rendered twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend

i'm new to react and i am working on a project with react frontend and java (Spring Boot) backend that performs some web scraping and returns data to react ui. Normally it's totally fine to render an element twice in development but i may banned due to sending too many requests in web scraping process. So i want to prevent that.

I have tried:

- Disabled devtools

but the issue is remaining

---

my component that being rendered twice:

```
import React from 'react';
import SearchService from '../../service/SearchService';
import BookShelf from '../fragment/BookShelf';
import PageHeader from '../fragment/PageHeader';
import LoadingScreen from '../modal/LoadingScreen';
import Error from '../fragment/Error';
import { Book } from '../../model/entity/Book';

class SearchPage extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

    this.state = {
      key: new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("key"),
      loading: false,
      user: user,
      searched: false,
    };

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const{key, searched} = this.state;

    if(!searched) {
        SearchService.search(key).then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
            this.setState({
                data: response.data,
                loading: false,
                searched: true,
            });
        }).catch(err => {
            this.setState({
                errorMessage: err.response.data,
                loading: false,
                searched: true,
            })
        });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const{user, loading, data, key, errorMessage} = this.state;

    const map = () => {
        const shelf = data.resultSet.map(result => 
            <div className='shelf-wrapper' key={result.source}>
                <h4 className='shelf-title'>{result.source}</h4>
                <div className="search-info">
                    <span>{"min: " + parseFloat(result.lowestPrice).toFixed(2) + ""}</span>
                    <span>{"average: " + parseFloat(result.averagePrice).toFixed(2) + " ₺"}</span>
                    <span>{"max: " + parseFloat(result.highestPrice).toFixed(2) + ""}</span>
                </div>
                <BookShelf bookList={result.result} compare={true}/> 
            </div>
        );
        return shelf;
    }

    return(
        <div className="container primary-background">
            { loading && 
                <LoadingScreen/>
            }

            <PageHeader/>

            <h1 className='center-align'>{"search results for: '" + key + "'"}</h1>
            { data &&
                map()
            }

            { errorMessage && 
                <Error message={errorMessage}/>
            }
        </div>
    );
  }

}

export default SearchPage;
```

[image]

---

and the router that rendering this component:

```
import './App.css';
import LoginPage from "./component/auth/login_page";
import SignupPage from "./component/auth/signup_page";
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import HomePage from "./component/home/home_page";
import UserService from './service/UserService';
import BookDetails from './component/book/BookDetails';
import SearchPage from './component/home/SearchPage';
import { disableReactDevTools } from '@fvilers/disable-react-devtools';
import { Component } from 'react';

disableReactDevTools();

export default class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
              <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage redirect="/home"/>}/>
              <Route path="/signup" element={<SignupPage/>}/>
              <Route path="/home" element={<HomePage/>}/>
              <Route path="/" element={<HomePage/>}/>
              <Route path="/search" element={<SearchPage/>}/>
              <Route path="/book/details" element={<BookDetails/>}/>
          </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the metric you are using for knowing with certainty it was rendered twice? Is it rendered twice or is it being remounted? We need a bit more detail.

Comment: i mean it's mounting twice, the componentDidMount method is being called twice and despite i have checked with if(!searched) inside of the if block is running twice.

Comment: I don't see any overt issues. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Sure, i have created it:
https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-haze-21xsso?file=/src/App.js

Comment: In your sandbox I see the `Search` component mounted twice (*i.e. 2 alerts*).... but your app is still rendered within a `React.StrictMode` component. Once `StrictMode` component is commented out, I see `Search` mounted only once (*i.e. only 1 alert*).

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state

Comment: I think chances are your actual code is still using the `React.StrictMode` component somewhere. The [Ensuring Reusable State](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state) feature mounts the wrapped component twice but takes the result of the initial mount. It still is a development-only effect, it doesn't do anything in production builds.

Comment: Yep, i have fixed the issue, it was another React.StrictMode located somewhere in my code. Deleted it and it works now. thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

For React.StrictMode issue, the solution can be your rendered component which renders twice that maybe wrap with React.StrictMode. Comment out or clean up the React.StrictMode, I hope it will fix.